# IPhone 6 auto case/pocket lock

Tags: iphone

I want to auto lock my IPhone 6 when entered to pocket/closed with case

Also my IPhone is **unjailbroken** and I want it to stay like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the given time without jailbreaking.

The iPhone does not have a magnetic sensor on the screen like the iPad.